# OS updates on SharePoint Server

Tags: 2013

I know that for SP 2013 CU's we have to run psconfig after the updates to sync SharePoint but do we have to do the same for OS updates on the SharePoint servers?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to run the config wizard after applying the OS updates. This is required only for the SharePoint Upates( CU/SP/PU).

But one thing make sure, while you applying the OS updates shut down the SharePoint so that no activity on SharePoint otherwise their might be issue with Sharepoint...i.e connectivity to DB server, accessing the files from hive folders( may corrupt the files), stopping services.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, kind of a newbie to SharePoint Server Admin. When you say "shut down" SharePoint, what specifically should be done?

Comment: for safe updates, i would recommend stop IIS, sharepoint timer service, admin services....you will be fine